# Read from .mat file

Tags: matlab, mat

working with MATLAB, I have a Matrix `M`, I want to save it in a `.mat` file then import it and reuse it in my code. I have tried:

```
save ('file1.mat','M')
MSaved=load('file1.mat');

Name   | Size    | Bytes | Class  | Attributes
-------+---------+-------+--------+-----------
MSaved | 4215x20 | 40744 | double |
```

How can I get access to each cell of the matrix? How to save it again in a matrix?

Need some help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load function will return a structure containing all the saved variables. So your matrix is MSaved.M

Comment: >> save example.mat M -v7.3;
>> MSaved = matfile('example.mat') ;
>> firstColB = MSaved.M(:,1);
>> EE=Msaved.M(:,:);
This is what I found as a solution, yes it is the same MSaved.M